# Circuit that allow the passage of the current and not its interruption

Tags: current

[image: circuit]

Hi guys. I have to make a circuit which allows the passage of current through human action but does not allow interruption of the current without removing the power source. I have designed the circuit in the photo. Are there other methods to do this? Is my method good?

From the image:
-Alimentazione means:power supply
-Interruttore means:switch

Comment: **alimentation** ˌalɪm(ə)nˈteɪʃ(ə)n, _noun formal_, 
"the provision of nourishment or other necessities of life." I think English is not your first language. Your question does not make sense yet. Please edit it to explain more what you want to know.

Comment: Excuse me:):)Alimentazione means alimentation.Interruttore means switch

Comment: *alimentation* isn't really an electrical term, either; I think you mean "power source", right?

Comment: also, the drawing you made is not a circuit – notice how current flows "into" your OUT, but not back into the current source? That is not a circuit (which needs to be a closed loop); please try to make a better drawing, in which you also note which wires go into the coil of the relais, and which wires go into the switching part of the relay!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sheesh... he used a very very thin ground wire that could only carry about 1nAmps. He drew it thin to match. zoom in on the photo and you will see it.

Comment: Search for Silicon Controlled Rectifier

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

- A person to be able to switch on a circuit.
- The circuit to stay on until power is removed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyblOu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) A relay latch. (b) A relay latch with OFF button.*

How it works:

- Person presses SW1.
- RLY1 coil is energised.
- Contact RLY1 closes. The relay will now stay on when the person releases SW1.
- The relay will now stay on until the power is removed.
- Add a normally closed switch for OFF button if you wish.

Connect your load (light, motor, etc.) to contact RLY1b.

[image]

*Figure 2. Animation of latching relay circuit.*

Comment: Is this the same circuit I have done but in a better way or the logic is different?

Comment: Rly1a what is?Is it the contact that the relè close when the coil is energized?

Comment: (1) You have not drawn a circuit that makes any sense. It is my guess about what you want. (2) I have drawn a relay with 2 contacts. One (1a) holds the relay on. The other (1b) is for your load (light, motor, etc.).

Comment: Ok,the two contacts are Rly1a and RLY1b?These two contacts colse when the coil is energized?

Comment: Correct. See animation.

Comment: Is possible to do this circuit using only a switch?

Comment: Then I haven't understood how the relais close the sw2 switch.Thanks for your disponibility:):)

Comment: Sorry, language is a big problem here. Is it possible to do _what_ using only a switch. (1) Please edit your original question. (2) Explain what you want to switch. (3) What voltage is it? What current is it? (4) How does the circuit turn on. (4) How does the circuit turn off? If you want try writing the full question in your own language and use http://translate.google.com to convert it into English.

Comment: "_Then I haven't understood how the relais close the sw2 switch._" You can get relays with 1, 2 , 3 or 4 contacts (switches). See http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-connect-a-double-pole-double-throw-relay-in-a-circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Feeding a Relay with the same voltage source that you switch is one method to build such a power supply, yes.

We call this kind of circuit *monostable* – because it has one "stable" state.

You can even buy already ready-made *monostable relais*; these include the circuit you want to build.

Of course, there's a lot of ways of doing something like this, and it depends very much on what kind of device you're switching on and off, and what voltages and currents are involved!

For example, if you're only switching small voltages/currents, the digital circuit that is equivalent to your relais-based circuit is called *monoflop*, and one can easily build it with one or two resistors and a transistor.

If you just need to turn on something, then a TRIAC can do that – the device stays turned on until there's no more current coming from the current source. However, this cannot work with the AC that comes out of the power outlet – because it's AC, the current runs first in one direction, and then in the other, and then again in the first direction – 50 or 60 times per second. However, in between, it is zero for a short time – and your TRIAC would turn off.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answare:):)In What Way i Can buld The digital circuit that You have mentioned in this part of your answare :"For example, if you're only switching small voltages/currents, the digital circuit that is equivalent to your relais-based circuit is called monoflop, and one can easily build it with one or two resistors and a transistor." ?

Comment: google for monoflop.